# How to use two microbits (3-axis magnetometers) to track an articulated arm?

Tags: python, geometry, bbc-microbit

I'm trying to use two microbits to track the motion of a human arm. Each microbit has one 3d-axis magnetometer and one 3d-axis accelerometer. I'm trying to use only the magnetometers to track the motion of the arm.

[image: Microbit axis]

The first microbit will be positioned over the biceps with the copper connectors pointing towards the elbow with the z-axis pointing towards the inside of the biceps. The second microbit will be positioned over the forearm with the z axis pointing towards the inside of the forearm like this

[image: Microbits positionig]

Each microbit will produce a vector from its magnetometers pointing towards the north in its coordinate system. The -y vector of the first microbit points in the direction from the shoulder to the elbow. The -y vector of the second microbit points in the direction from the elbow to the hand.
If I have the unit vectors pointing in the -y directions of the two microbits in the same coordinate system I can just multiply each vector by the length of each arm segment, plot vector 2 at the end of vector 1, and voila a perfect representation of that joint.

To do this, my initial plan is to project the north vector generated by the second microbit into the yz plane (for all intents and purposes, the two arm segments will always be contained in the yz plane), find the angle between the north projection and the vector - y. Using this angle I would take the projection of the north vector generated by the first microbit onto the yz plane and rotate it through this angle finally finding the -y vector of microbit 2 in the microbit 1 coordinate system.

```py
import numpy as np
from kaspersmicrobit import KaspersMicrobit

def get_angle(v1, v2):
    v1_mag = np.linalg.norm(v1)
    v2_mag = np.linalg.norm(v2)
    v1_unit = v1 / v1_mag
    v2_unit = v2 / v2_mag
    cos_angle = np.dot(v1_unit, v2_unit)
    angle = np.arccos(cos_angle)
    cross_product = np.cross(v1_unit, v2_unit)
    if float(cross_product) < 0:
        angle = 2 * np.pi - angle
    return angle

class JointTracker:
    def __init__(self, *microbits: str | KaspersMicrobit) -> None:
        self.microbits = self.get_connection(microbits)
        self.vectors: List[np.ndarray(shape=3, dtype=float)] = []
        self.gravity_north_angle = None

    def update(self):
        vectors = [np.array([0, -1, 0])]
        north0 = self._get_magnetometer(self.microbits[0])
        north0_yz = np.array([north0[1], north0[2]])
        for microbit in self.microbits[1:]:
            northn = self._get_magnetometer(microbit)
            northn_yz = np.array([northn[1], northn[2]])
            theta = get_angle(np.array([-1, 0]), northn_yz)
            r = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)],
                         [0, -np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
            narm_vector = np.dot(
                r, np.array([0, north0[1], north0[2]]))\
                / np.linalg.norm(north0_yz)
            vectors.append(narm_vector)
        self.vectors = vectors
        # From here on down I'm also trying to track the "shoulder movement" so to speak. I try to
        # find the angles of the yz plane with respect to north by projecting the north vector 
        # onto the xy and xz planes and calculating the angle between these vectors and the -y
        # vector, then rotating all the vectors representing the arm by these angles.
        # But since I'm not even able to track the movement of the elbow, I decided to leave that 
        # for later.
        # rot_vectors = []
        # north0_xy = np.array([north0[0], north0[1]])
        # phi = get_angle(north0_xy, np.array([0, 1]))
        # rphi = np.array([[np.cos(phi), np.sin(phi), 0],
        #                 [-np.sin(phi), np.cos(phi), 0],
        #                 [0, 0, 1]])
        # north0_xz = np.array([north0[0], north0[2]])
        # gama = get_angle(north0_xz, np.array([0, 1]))
        # rgama = np.array([[np.cos(gama), 0, -np.sin(gama)],
        #                  [0, 1, 0],
        #                  [np.sin(gama), 0, np.cos(gama)]])
        # for vector in vectors:
        #    rot_vectors.append(np.dot(rgama, np.dot(rphi, vector)))
        # self.vectors = rot_vectors
```

I made it and plotted those vectors with matplotlib. And what I see is not what I want.

[image: Tilted]

When positioning the microbits as a completely open arm (180 degrees between arm and forearm) the forearm seems to be slightly tilted relative to the arm in the vector representation. When simulating closing the arm, the angle between the vectors appears to reduce twice as fast as the actual angle. When the real vector is about 90 degrees, the angle in the vector representation is about 190~200 degrees. Another thing I noticed is that depending on where I do the tests with the microbits, the results are different. I don't know exactly what I'm doing wrong and, to be honest, I'm running out of ideas and out of time. Is there something wrong with my code? Did I do something wrong in the geometry part? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?
Please help.

The full code is on https://github.com/estevaopbs/microbit_tracker but I believe I put everything needed in this post.